# Power BI, How to summarize following table (Max, distinctcount)

Tags: count, max, powerbi, dax

```html
Date Customer Sales 
2018-01-01 A 36 
2018-01-01 A 45 
2018-01-01 B 16 
2018-01-01 C 31 
2018-01-02 D 29 
2018-01-02 D 29 
2018-01-02 A 26 
2018-01-02 B 35 
2018-01-03 C 12
2018-01-03 C 32 
2018-01-03 A 33
2018-01-03 B 32
```

I've been spending several day & nights solving following using DAX in POWER BI.

From the attached 'Raw data' table , I'd like to have the summry like attached aside.[Raw Data and Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7Pv.png)

Raw Data
Date        Customer    Sales
2018-01-01  A   36
2018-01-01  A   45
2018-01-01  B   16
2018-01-01  C   31
2018-01-02  D   29
2018-01-02  D   29
2018-01-02  A   26
2018-01-02  B   35
2018-01-03  C   12
2018-01-03  C   32
2018-01-03  A   33
2018-01-03  B   32

Comment: If you add your sample data into the question in a format that people can copy and paste into Excel it'd be better.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Comment: No problem. I've added an answer that uses a Calculated Table (which you can do in Power BI but not in Excel Power Pivot). No doubt there's a solution that wouldn't need a calculated table, but I quite like the simplicity of it actually...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it...

Raw data:

[image]

1. Create a new Calculated Table

[image]

Add a Matrix and add, from your new calculated table, Customer on Rows and DailyOrders into Values three times, setting one to `Count` and one to `Maximum`.

[image]

**The resulting Matrix:**

[image]

Comment: It really worked in solving my real headache.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if it worked out for you :)